# How to get nested data using AppSync generated query?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have the following graphql schema:

```
type Post
  @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  content: String!

  comments: [Comment] @hasMany(indexName: "byPost", fields: ["id"])
}

type Comment
  @model {
  id: ID!
  message: String
  post: Post @belongsTo(fields: ["postID"])
  postID: ID @index(name: "byPost")
}
```

AppSync generated the following query for this schema:

```
export const listPosts = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListPosts(
    $filter: ModelPostFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listPosts(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        title
        content
        comments {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

Now when I use it like this:

```
const postData = await API.graphql({
      query: listPosts,
    });
```

There are no comments in result, is returns `comments: { nextToken: null }` as part of a post, but there are comments, associated with the post in the database.

How can I get nested data in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Build your answer without `@belongsTo`.

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  comments: [Comment] @hasMany
}

type Comment @model {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
}
```

You can learn more about `hasMany` [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#has-many-relationship).

Test your expectations via the AWS AppSync console before writing front-end code solutions.